# Consider the smallest sigma algebra containing all intervals of the form $(-\infty, a)$ for $a \in\Bbb R$. Show that it contains $(a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have no issues with showing that $[a,b)$ is in the sigma algebra, but I just can't figure out how to do $(a,b]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$\left(\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}}\left(-\infty, c+\frac1n\right)\right)\setminus\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}}\left(-\infty,d+\frac1m\right)=\boxed{????} $$

Comment: Wow, that makes it so easy, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In this answer it is only used that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under complements and countable unions.

It will contain $[a,\infty)=(-\infty,a)^{\complement}$.

It will contain $(a,\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[a+\frac1n,\infty)$.

It will contain $(-\infty,a]=(a,\infty)^{\complement}$.

It will contain $(a,b]=\left[(-\infty,a]\cup(b,\infty)\right]^{\complement}$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Shouldn't the 2nd one be a + 1/n instead of a - 1/n?

Comment: @Bob You are right. Thanks in return and repaired.